# Question on Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $I=[0,1]$, and let $(I, B, m)$ be a Borel space and $(I, L, m')$ a Lebesgue space.

--- Is it true that each open set in $L$ is already in $B$.

If so, can some provide some steps like a proof.

Comment: What do you mean by a Borel space? A space with $\sigma$-algebra generated by the usual open intervals topology? Or can it be any topology?

Comment: Yes, open interval topology. Do you think there will be a difference for other topologies?

Comment: Well, let $L$ be the standard Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, let $N$ be any subset of $I$, and consider the topology $ \{∅ , N , N^c , I\}$. This is also a $\sigma$-algebra. And there are plenty of sets in $L$ that are not in $B$.

Comment: Great. What about standard Borel $\sigma$-algebra ?

Comment: Assuming that "a" Lebesgue space is the standard Lebesgue space on $I$, $B$ with the open intervals topology almost by definition contains every open subset of $I$. So it doesn't matter that $L$ is a Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, every open subset of $I$ that happens to be in $L$ (or not) is already in $B$.

Comment: Can  we prove this or this is trivially true ?

Comment: I feel that that is the proof. Which sentence would you like clarified?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No, this is just come to mind to mind. Thanks a lot for your time and your comments. I got it well.

Comment: OK. I only ask because if this was homework, I would think you might have misunderstood the question because it can't be that easy :P Have a good day!